# Visual Studio "No certificate found with the supplied thumb print"

Tags: vb.net, uwp

I am trying to deploy a UWP written in VB.NET on my Surface Book from Visual Studio (debugging).  I have deployed this application on my Surface tablet and multiple other devices from Visual Studio in debug mode many times and it has deployed flawlessly.

However, my Surface Book gives the error:

> "No certificate found with the supplied thumbprint:
>   B24292B81DF0CE5DA065AECC8D19AD4A5973E9A2" when attempting to deploy. 
>   This prevents deployment completely.

I have searched all over for this error message and cannot find any solution.  No one seems to have had a similar issue!

What could this be?

Comment: So, did this issue only occur on your surface book device? Have you any other surface book device to test to see if you will face the same issue?

Comment: I have the same issue with a UWP app written in C#. I bet it is a regression on a latest VS update. I was able to deploy the app with no issue. I just took a 3 week vacations and now I can't deploy anymore.

Comment: You can be unblocked following this fix by Rudy: https://github.com/microsoft/calculator/pull/617

Latest VS update added more restriction.

Comment: How do you find the correct value of the certificate?

Answer (score 2):

I have had this problem (or a similar one) before where I couldn't deploy because of an invalid security certificate.
If you go to the project Properties->Signing and create a new test certificate then that should fix the issue. It could be that it was expired or on a new development PC.
You could also try unchecking 'sign the ClickOnce Manifests".

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all of your responses, everyone!  I was fiddling around and managed to somehow get it to deploy.  I believe it had to do with re-targeting the application for a different version of Windows.  The Surface book was on a much newer version of Windows than my other devices.  I had to install the SDK for the previous versions of Windows on it.  After doing this, I had to re-reference all of my class libraries.  Then it worked after a reboot!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem while testing an old app in VS.  Apparently the "thumbprint" expires after 1 year.  The solution was to create a new "thumbprint" by in Visual Studio Pro...

- open project "Properties" (highlight project and hit Alt-Enter),
- look for "Application" in the left margin and select it,
- Select the "Package Manifest" button,
- VS will now display the Package.appxmanifest page (this is a UWP project),
- select the "Packaging" tab (starts with "Application" on the left),
- select "Choose Certificate" button,
- on the "Choose a Certificate" popup dialog select the "Create" button,
- on the "Create a Self-Signed Test Certificate" popup leave type something for "Publisher Common Name" but you can leave both password fields blank if you are testing.
- select "Ok" button.

Now your project should have a "thumbprint" certificate and you can test.

Live/Commercial Deployment will need a real certificate.  If you are deploying to the MSFT Store the process will create a certificate for you if you are properly registered with the Store.